# having error when using Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium mode

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate a network in which my RadioMedium is set to `Ieee80211DimensionalRadioMedium` to support a partially overlapped channel capability. But in simulation runtime, an error as following is occurred:

> check_and_cast(): Cannot cast (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211ScalarTransmission*) to type 'const inet::physicallayer::DimensionalTransmission *' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::Ieee80211Radio) Net80211.host[12].wlan[0].radio (id=836), at t=1.080873885294s, event #252

That is the cause of the mentioned error? Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same issue. what causes this ?